# React Native :Button onPress not working

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation

Navigation not working on button press.This is my login page.I want to logout 
 from home screen to  login screen on onPressLogout()

**index.js**

```
class Profile extends Component{
static propTypes = {
    navigator: PropTypes.shape({
        getCurrentRoutes: PropTypes.func,
        jumpTo: PropTypes.func,
    }),
}
onPressLogout() {
    const routeStack = this.props.navigator.getCurrentRoutes();
    this.props.navigator.jumpTo(routeStack[0]);
}
render(){
  return (
         <Container>
             <View style={styles.container}>        
               <Header>
                     <Button 
                     style={styles.button}
                     onPress={() => this.onPressLogout()}
                     >
                     <Icon name="ios-power" />
                     </Button>
                     <Title>Logout</Title>
               </Header>
            </Container>
 );
}
```

and in routeStack

```
const routeStack = [
{ name: 'Login', component: Login},  
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use `.bind()` to change the context of `this`. Or, use arrow functions.

**`bind()`**

This requires a constructor.

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.onPressLogout = this.onPressLogout.bind(this);
}
```

**Arrow functions**

```
onPressLogout = () => {
  const routeStack = this.props.navigator.getCurrentRoutes();
  this.props.navigator.jumpTo(routeStack[0]);
}
```

Side note:

You could do some ES6 destructuring here

```
onPressLogout = () => {
  const {
     navigator: {
       getCurrentRoutes,
       jumpTo
     }
  } = this.props;
  const routeStack = getCurrentRoutes();
  jumpTo(routeStack[0]);
}
```

Comment: I have tried both methods but still same error `undefined is not an object:evaluating _this$props$navigator.getCurrentRoutes`

Comment: Are you able to just console.log `this.props.navigator` and comment back with the result?

Comment: It is  showing some error in console. I tried to alert but no result.